# .h file crossed out and grayed out in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using a project created by someone else and several pre-existing files are grayed out and crossed out in my project explorer. This question tells how to handle the .c files but the option does not work for the .h files:

[What would cause my source files to be greyed out with a strikethrough through the file icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127299/what-would-cause-my-source-files-to-be-greyed-out-with-a-strikethrough-through-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on header file in project explorer, select Properies menu item. In the item `Properties` dialog switch to `C/C++ Build`, uncheck `Exclude resource from build` checkbox. Notice that excluding /including header file in general has no effect as it is not supposed to be compiled.

[image]

This method should work on .c files as well.